How to iterate through a JSON array and read a specific value using Logic App?
[XML][1]
[Converted JSON from XML][2]
I am trying to read a XML file & converting it to a JSON file. The JSON file contains multiple worker records and I want to iterate through all the worker records and read the specific value.
Sample of converted JSON
   {
  "?xml": {
    "@version": "1.0",
    "@encoding": "UTF-8"
  },
  "ws:Worker_Sync": {
    "@xmlns:ws": "urn:com.workday/workersync",
    "@xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    "ws:Header": {
      "ws:Version": "25.0",
      "ws:Prior_Entry_Time": "2024-05-06T23:04:49.766-07:00",
      "ws:Current_Entry_Time": "2024-05-07T07:01:49.768-07:00",
      "ws:Prior_Effective_Time": "2024-11-02T00:00:00.000-07:00",
      "ws:Current_Effective_Time": "2024-11-03T00:00:00.000-07:00",
      "ws:Full_File": "false",
      "ws:Document_Retention_Policy": "90",
      "ws:Worker_Count": "2"
    },
    "ws:Worker": [
      {
        "ws:Summary": {
          "ws:Employee_ID": "18325",
          "ws:Name": "test"
        },
        "ws:Eligibility": {
          "@ws:PriorValue": "",
          "#text": "true"
        },
        "ws:Personal": {
          "ws:Name_Data": {
            "ws:First_Name": {
              "@ws:PriorValue": "",
              "#text": "test"
            },
            "ws:Last_Name": {
              "@ws:PriorValue": "",
              "#text": "test"
            }
          }
        },
        "ws:Status": {
          "ws:Staffing_Event": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "HIR"
          },
          "ws:Staffing_Event_Date": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "2024-05-13"
          },
          "ws:Employee_Status": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "Active"
          },
          "ws:Active": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "true"
          },
          "ws:Active_Status_Date": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "2024-05-13"
          },
          "ws:Hire_Date": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "2024-05-13"
          },
          "ws:Hire_Reason": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "Hire_Employee_Hire_Employee_New_Hire"
          },
          "ws:End_Employment_Date": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "2024-08-02"
          },
          "ws:Rehire": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "false"
          }
        },
        "ws:Position": {
          "ws:Operation": "ADD",
          "ws:Effective_Date": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "2024-05-13"
          },
          "ws:Position_Title": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "Intern"
          },
          "ws:Business_Title": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "Co-Operative Student"
          },
          "ws:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "36.25"
          },
          "ws:Organization_Data": [
            {
              "ws:Operation": "ADD",
              "ws:Organization": {
                "@ws:PriorValue": "",
                "#text": "953"
              }
            },
            {
              "ws:Operation": "ADD",
              "ws:Organization": {
                "@ws:PriorValue": "",
                "#text": "test"
              }
            }
          ],
          "ws:Business_Site_Name": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:Supervisor": {
            "ws:Operation": "ADD",
            "ws:Supervisor_Name": {
              "@ws:PriorValue": "",
              "#text": "test"
            }
          }
        },
        "ws:Additional_Information": {
          "ws:Mobile_Number": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:Legal_Name": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:Preferred_Name": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:SUPERVISORY_ORG": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:COST_CENTRE": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:USERNAME": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "stest"
          },
          "ws:Annual_Leave_Balance": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "5"
          },
          "ws:Company": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "test"
          },
          "ws:Job_Profile": {
            "@ws:PriorValue": "",
            "#text": "Intern"
          }
        }
      }
         
    ]
  }
}

The logic app designer
I am trying to iterate through the ws:worker array and fetch the value from {"ws:Worker" --> "ws:Status"  --> "ws:Staffing_Event" --> "#text"
When I run the logic app, I get the following error:
The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@body('Parse_JSON_FIle')?['ws:Worker']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.
Please can you share your insights.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/wi0QD03Y.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/3qsr4ElD.png

Can you provide an example of your XML file, which fails?

Can you provide the converted json

@RithwikBojja  I have added a sample record of converted JSON from the XML file in the image section as I was not able to edit the post because of the characters constraint.

If you provide in image, one cannot use it, provide sample xml in text format or else give xml data in text format in question

@RithwikBojja  I have removed the Logic app code and posted the sample of converted JSON from XML.

@RithwikBojja thank you for your patience. It was a typo error and  I have uploaded full sample JSON with 1 worker record.

@RithwikBojja I want to read the value of the below #text field for all worker records.
ws:Worker" --> "ws:Status" --> "ws:Staffing_Event" --> "#text"

@RithwikBojja Thank you. I was using the same approach but was skipping the ['ws:Worker_Sync']. I was using the ws:Worker from the Parsed JSON content which did not had the ['ws:Worker_Sync'].
Please can you describe why would we include it for my understanding as I thought ['ws:Worker_Sync'] and ['ws:Worker'] are 2 different objects.

You are getting this error –

the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@body('Parse_JSON_FIle')?['ws:Worker']' is of type 'Null'

– because the ws:Worker array is inside the ws:Worker_Sync object, so your For each action should loop over @body('Parse_JSON_FIle')?['ws:Worker_Sync']?['ws:Worker'].
Then, inside your loop you'll be able to get the @item()?['ws:Status']?['ws:Staffing_Event']?['#text'] value.

yes, I can iterate through it now. Thank you very much for your help.

For the json you have provided below is the design which worked for me:
body('Parse_JSON')?['ws:Worker_Sync']?['ws:Worker']?['ws:Status']?['ws:Staffing_Event']?['#text']


Parse Json schema which worked for me for your input:
    {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "?xml": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "@@version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@encoding": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "ws:Worker_Sync": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "@@xmlns:ws": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "@@xmlns:xsi": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "ws:Header": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "ws:Version": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Prior_Entry_Time": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Current_Entry_Time": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Prior_Effective_Time": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Current_Effective_Time": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Full_File": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Document_Retention_Policy": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "ws:Worker_Count": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ws:Worker": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "ws:Summary": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "ws:Employee_ID": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ws:Name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ws:Eligibility": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "#text": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ws:Personal": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "ws:Name_Data": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "ws:First_Name": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "#text": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "ws:Last_Name": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "#text": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ws:Status": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "ws:Staffing_Event": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Staffing_Event_Date": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Employee_Status": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Active": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Active_Status_Date": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Hire_Date": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Hire_Reason": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:End_Employment_Date": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Rehire": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ws:Position": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "ws:Operation": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "ws:Effective_Date": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Position_Title": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Business_Title": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Scheduled_Weekly_Hours": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Organization_Data": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "ws:Operation": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "ws:Organization": {
                                                "type": "object",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "#text": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": [
                                            "ws:Operation",
                                            "ws:Organization"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Business_Site_Name": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Supervisor": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "ws:Operation": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "ws:Supervisor_Name": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "#text": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "ws:Additional_Information": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "ws:Mobile_Number": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Legal_Name": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Preferred_Name": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:SUPERVISORY_ORG": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:COST_CENTRE": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:USERNAME": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Annual_Leave_Balance": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Company": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "ws:Job_Profile": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "@@ws:PriorValue": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "#text": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


How has this worked if ws:Worker is an array? Which item of the array your @body('Parse_JSON')?['ws:Worker_Sync']?['ws:Worker']?['ws:Status']?['ws:Staffing_Event']?['#text'] expression would return?

Try and check it, it will work and I have even posted with screen shots to show output. It will return the staffing event which you asked in question

It wasn't me who raised the question :) Perhaps your schema is wrong, I didn't check, but the fact is that this is an array, so with more than 1 item in the array your answer won't be too helpful.

yes, 10p but op has given the json and for that json this is working, if it is a array then t will not. And i thought i was replying to Op.
